# How to use shell variables in perl command call in a bash shell script?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk

How to use shell variables in perl command call in a bash shell script?

I have a perl command in my shell script to evaluate date -1.

How can i use `$myDate` in perl command call?

This is the section in my script:

```
myDate='10/10/2012'

Dt=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime '%m/%d/%y', localtime time-86400;")
```

I want use `$myDate` in place of `%m/%d/%y`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Replacing `'%m/%d/%y'` with the value of `myDate` doesn't make any sense unless you change the value of `myDate` to something like `%m/%d/%y`. Please fix your question appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you pass values to any other program: Pass it as an arg. (You might be tempted to generate Perl code, but that's a bad idea.)

```
Dt=$( perl -MPOSIX -e'print strftime $ARGV[0], localtime time-86400;' -- "$myDate" )
```

Note that code doesn't always return yesterday's date (since not all days have 86400 seconds). For that, you'd want

```
Dt=$( perl -MPOSIX -e'my @d = localtime time-86400; --$d[4]; print strftime $ARGV[0], @d;' -- "$myDate" )
```

or

```
Dt=$( perl -MDateTime -e'print DateTime->today(time_zone => "local")->subtract(days => 1)->strftime($ARGV[0]);' -- "$myDate" )
```

or simply

```
Dt=$( date --date='1 day ago' +"$myDate" )
```

Comment: This post assumes you want to use `myDate` as the format specifier as you said, which means that `myDate` actually contains something like `%m/%d/%y`.

Answer (score 36):

Variables from the shell are available in Perl's `%ENV` hash. With `bash` (and some other shells) you need to take the extra step of "exporting" your shell variable so it is visible to subprocesses.

```
mydate=10/10/2012
export mydate
perl -e 'print "my date is $ENV{mydate}\n"'
```

Comment: This is a simple answer that rules. The one above just looks like some convoluted complex code that I can't understand

Comment: Also, if you run `perl -p`, then it interprets the `--` as a filename, so it is only possible to use $ENV in such scripts

Comment: @henley-chiu : In fairness to 
@ikegami's accepted answer, using the "-- arg" approach avoids polluting the bash environment, whereas using `export` in a bash function or alias means that running a function/alias with `export` will result in "mydate" being set for the duration of a bash session.

Answer (score 8):

Using `"` instead of `'` also passes shell variables to perl in version 5.24.

```
mydate=22/6/2016
perl -e "print $mydate"
```

Comment: This is what Ikegami recommends against in the accepted answer, for good reason.  If you have complete control over `mydate` and understand what you are doing, interpolating it as Perl code is fine ... but that is certainly not true in this case, and so this snippet will produce erratic output `0.00181878306878307`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I need to use `$ENV{'VARIABLE'}` to pass `VARIABLE` in shell to Perl. I do not know why simply `$ENV{VARIABLE}` did not work.

For example,

In Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
VARIABLE=1
export VARIABLE
perl example.pl
```

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "my number is " . $ENV{'VARIABLE'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like:
`$ENV{'PATH'} = $ENV{'PATH'}.":"."/additional/path";`