# How to randomly find and replace only one occurance of a match in a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I am using `sed` to find and replace items in a file:

```
sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" ./file.txt
```

This will replace all appearances in a file.

Is there any way to randomly replace just one of the occurrences within an entire file?

- The match might appear on any line or even multiple times within a file, but should only be replaced once.

Comment: Randomly? Doubt it (but I don't know `sed`). Once? Get rid of the `g`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`, you can use [`rand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) function:

```
perl -lane '
    while ($n = rand @F) { 
        if ($F[$n] eq "pattern") { 
            $F[$n] = "replacement"; 
            print "@F"; 
            last 
        } 
    }
' file
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094238/970195) post, variables from the shell are available in perl's `%ENV` hash. With `bash` (and some other shells) you need to take the extra step of "exporting" your shell variable so it is visible to subprocesses.

So in your case, you'll have to do:

```
pattern="mypattern"
replacement="myreplacement"
export pattern
export replacement
perl -lane '
    while ($n = rand @F) { 
        if ($F[$n] eq "$ENV{pattern}") { 
            $F[$n] = "$ENV{replacement}"; 
            print "@F"; 
            last 
        } 
    }
' file
```

Of course, this will print to STDOUT so if you need to make in-file changes, you can either use `-i` command line option or redirect the output to another file.

Alternatively, if this is not part of your `bash` script and you want to do it in `perl`, then you can pass the pattern and replacement on the command line.

```
perl -lane '
BEGIN { ($patt, $repl) = splice @ARGV, 1 }
while ($n = rand @F) {
  if ($F[$n] eq $patt) {
    $F[$n] = $repl;
    print "@F";
    last
  }
}' file "pattern" "replacement"
```

This will do replacement randomly once per line. If you wish to do it once per file, please leave a comment and I will add that version.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use List::Util qw(shuffle);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search = shift @ARGV;
my $repl = shift @ARGV;
my @lines;
my @matches;

while (<>) {
    push(@lines, $_);
    push(@matches, $.) if /$search/;
}

my @shuffled = shuffle(@matches);
my $index = shift @shuffled;

if ($index) {
    $lines[$index - 1] =~ s/$search/$repl/;
}

print @lines;
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl string replacement file
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this truly randomly would be to inventory all the locations of the PATTERN first.   Otherwise there is no way to give proper weighting.

The following does the replacement via a script.  It only replaces the first reference of a pattern on a specific line currently:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = '...';
my $pattern = qr/.../;
my $replace = '...';

my @linenums;
local @ARGV = $file;
while (<>) {
    push @linenums, $_ if $_ =~ $pattern;
}

my $linenum = $linenums[rand @linenums];

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    s/$pattern/$replace/ if $. == $linenum;
    print;
}
# unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally Delete backup
```

#### Addendum for PATTERN on line more than once.

If you want to allow a pattern to be on a line more than once, the following enhancement would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = '...';
my $pattern = qr/.../;
my $replace = '...';

my @linenums;
local @ARGV = $file;
while (<>) {
    my $count = () = $_ =~ /$pattern/g;
    push @linenums, {line => $., num => $_} for 0 .. $count - 1;
}

die "No matches found" unless @linenums;

my $pick = $linenums[rand @linenums];

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    if ($. == $pick->{line}) {
        s/(?:$pattern.*?){$pick->{num}}\K$pattern/$replace/;
    }
    print;
}
# unlink "$file$^I"; # Optionally Delete backup
```